# How to remove breakpoints causing Chrome to hang

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Is it possible to delete all breakpoints *without* opening Chrome devtools?

I have a breakpoint set in a large obfuscated javascript file that cause the current tab to hang if I have devtools open while the page loads. I have no problems if i let the page load, and then open the devtools, but then the script is not visible in the sources and network panels.

I have attempted to disable breakpoints by immediately activating the "Deactivate all breakpoints" button when the page loads, but the breakpoint still triggers causing the tab to hang.

Update: This problem only happens when the *sources* panel in the devtools is open during page load.

Comment: If you don't have devtools opened, breakpoints simply don't exist. Maybe it's not breakpoints that causes hangs of your browser

Comment: @Magnus, you can find the script using full text search (it's inside the lower console docker toolbar, also Ctrl-Shift-F ) if you enable "Search in anonymous and content scripts" in devtools settings.

Comment: @Andrey The problem happens whenever that script is display in the sources panel, only happens when devtools is open during page load. I updated the issue to clarify.

Comment: @wOxxOm Cool, I did not know about this setting :) but alas the search does not include any content from this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to reset the devtools, including all breakpoints, by simply logging out of chrome and back in again.

Answer (score 3):

As @Andrey points out, when the dev tools are closed Chrome will **never** break on a breakpoint.

You can disable breakpoints using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> afterwards will continue from the current breakpoint.

[image: Disable breakpoints- Chrome]

You can also view a summary of all active BP's in the right of dev tools.

[image: Breakpoints summary - Chrome]

**Update:**
A *last resort* option is to clear the dev tools settings as follows. Note this will clear reset any customized settings you have...

`Settings` > `Restore defaults and reload`

[image: Dev Tools reset - Chrome]

Comment: I have tried this and it still freezes even if the Disable breakpoints option is active :/

Comment: @Magnus in that case I suggest resetting the dev tools settings which will clear any break points you have.